# STM32F4 - CAN bus transmit succeeds every time, but CAN receive only succeeds on the first call

Tags: interrupt, stm32, can-bus, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I'm using an STM32F469 Discovery board and I'm trying to use the CAN features.

I understand that on this board CAN1 cannot be used at the same time as the touchscreen. Therefore I need to use CAN2, but in order to enable CAN2, CAN1 needs to be enabled.

My code for configuration/callback is as follows:

```c
/* CAN1 Values */
#define CAN1_CLK_ENABLE()         __HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLE()
#define CAN1_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE()    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE()
#define CAN1_FORCE_RESET()        __HAL_RCC_CAN1_FORCE_RESET()
#define CAN1_RELEASE_RESET()      __HAL_RCC_CAN1_RELEASE_RESET()
#define CAN1_TX_PIN              GPIO_PIN_9
#define CAN1_TX_GPIO_PORT        GPIOB
#define CAN1_TX_AF               GPIO_AF9_CAN1
#define CAN1_RX_PIN              GPIO_PIN_8
#define CAN1_RX_GPIO_PORT        GPIOB
#define CAN1_RX_AF               GPIO_AF9_CAN1
#define CAN1_RX_IRQn             CAN1_RX0_IRQn
#define CAN1_RX_IRQHandler       CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler

/* CAN2 Values */
#define CAN2_CLK_ENABLE()         __HAL_RCC_CAN2_CLK_ENABLE()
#define CAN2_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE()    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE()
#define CAN2_FORCE_RESET()        __HAL_RCC_CAN2_FORCE_RESET()
#define CAN2_RELEASE_RESET()      __HAL_RCC_CAN2_RELEASE_RESET()
#define CAN2_TX_PIN              GPIO_PIN_13
#define CAN2_TX_GPIO_PORT        GPIOB
#define CAN2_TX_AF               GPIO_AF9_CAN2
#define CAN2_RX_PIN              GPIO_PIN_5
#define CAN2_RX_GPIO_PORT        GPIOB
#define CAN2_RX_AF               GPIO_AF9_CAN2
#define CAN2_RX_IRQn             CAN2_RX0_IRQn
#define CAN2_RX_IRQHandler       CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler

CAN_HandleTypeDef CanHandle1;
CAN_HandleTypeDef CanHandle2;

static uint8_t Message_Data[8];

static void CAN1_Config(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    CAN_FilterConfTypeDef CAN_FilterInitStructure;

    static CanTxMsgTypeDef TxMessage;
    static CanRxMsgTypeDef RxMessage;

    /* CAN1 peripheral clock enable */
    CAN1_CLK_ENABLE();
    CAN1_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* CAN1 TX GPIO pin configuration */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CAN1_TX_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate =  CAN1_TX_AF;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(CAN1_TX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* CAN1 RX GPIO pin configuration */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CAN1_RX_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate =  CAN1_RX_AF;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(CAN1_RX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* NVIC configuration for CAN1 reception complete interrupt */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(CAN1_RX_IRQn, 1, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN1_RX_IRQn);

    CanHandle1.Instance = CAN1;
    CanHandle1.pTxMsg = &TxMessage;
    CanHandle1.pRxMsg = &RxMessage;

    /* CAN peripheral init */
    CanHandle1.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
    CanHandle1.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
    CanHandle1.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
    CanHandle1.Init.NART = DISABLE;
    CanHandle1.Init.RFLM = DISABLE;
    CanHandle1.Init.TXFP = DISABLE;
    CanHandle1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_LOOPBACK;
    CanHandle1.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
    CanHandle1.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_6TQ;
    CanHandle1.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_8TQ;
    CanHandle1.Init.Prescaler = 2;

    HAL_CAN_Init(&CanHandle1);

    /* CAN filter init */
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterNumber = 0;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.BankNumber = 0;

    HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&CanHandle1, &CAN_FilterInitStructure);

    /* Configure transmission */
    CanHandle1.pTxMsg->StdId = 0x7DF;
    CanHandle1.pTxMsg->ExtId = 0x7DF;
    CanHandle1.pTxMsg->RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    CanHandle1.pTxMsg->IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
    CanHandle1.pTxMsg->DLC = 8;
}

static void CAN2_Config(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    CAN_FilterConfTypeDef CAN_FilterInitStructure;

    static CanTxMsgTypeDef TxMessage;
    static CanRxMsgTypeDef RxMessage;

    /* CAN2 peripheral clock enable */
    CAN2_CLK_ENABLE();
    CAN2_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* CAN2 TX GPIO pin configuration */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CAN2_TX_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate =  CAN2_TX_AF;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(CAN2_TX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* CAN2 RX GPIO pin configuration */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CAN2_RX_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate =  CAN2_RX_AF;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(CAN2_RX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* NVIC configuration for CAN2 reception complete interrupt */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(CAN2_RX_IRQn, 1, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN2_RX_IRQn);

    CanHandle2.Instance = CAN2;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg = &TxMessage;
    CanHandle2.pRxMsg = &RxMessage;

    /* CAN peripheral init */
    CanHandle2.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
    CanHandle2.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
    CanHandle2.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
    CanHandle2.Init.NART = DISABLE;
    CanHandle2.Init.RFLM = DISABLE;
    CanHandle2.Init.TXFP = DISABLE;
    CanHandle2.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_LOOPBACK;
    CanHandle2.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
    CanHandle2.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_6TQ;
    CanHandle2.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_8TQ;
    CanHandle2.Init.Prescaler = 2;

    HAL_CAN_Init(&CanHandle2);

    /* CAN filter init */
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterNumber = 0; //14 enables CAN1;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.BankNumber = 0; // 14 enables CAN1

    HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&CanHandle2, &CAN_FilterInitStructure);

    /* Configure transmission */
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->StdId = 0x7DF;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->ExtId = 0x7DF;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->DLC = 8;
}

void HAL_CAN_RxCpltCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef* CanHandle)
{
    EwBspYellowLedOn();

    Message_Data[0] = CanHandle->pRxMsg->Data[0];
    Message_Data[1] = CanHandle->pRxMsg->Data[1];
    Message_Data[2] = CanHandle->pRxMsg->Data[2];
    Message_Data[3] = CanHandle->pRxMsg->Data[3];
    Message_Data[4] = CanHandle->pRxMsg->Data[4];
    Message_Data[5] = CanHandle->pRxMsg->Data[5];
    Message_Data[6] = CanHandle->pRxMsg->Data[6];
    Message_Data[7] = CanHandle->pRxMsg->Data[7];

    if (HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(CanHandle, CAN_FIFO0) != HAL_OK)
    {
        EwBspRedLedOn();
    }
}

CAN_Transmit_Message(void)
{
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->StdId = 0x7DF;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->ExtId = 0x7DF;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->Data[0] = 0x02;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->Data[1] = 0x01;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->Data[2] = 0x0D;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->Data[3] = 0x55;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->Data[4] = 0x55;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->Data[5] = 0x55;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->Data[6] = 0x55;
    CanHandle2.pTxMsg->Data[7] = 0x55;

    if (HAL_CAN_Transmit(&CanHandle, 10) != HAL_OK)
    {
        EwBspOrangeLedOn();
    }

    HAL_Delay(10);
}
```

I then run the following in my main function to configure the CAN1, CAN2 and the interrupt:

```c
    /* Configure interrupt for CAN transmission */
    CAN1_Config();
    CAN2_Config();
    HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(&CanHandle2, CAN_FIFO0);
```

And then I run the `CAN_Transmit_Message()`.

When doing this I have verified the message successfully transmits (the orange LED does *not* turn on), the receive interrupt handler is then executed (yellow LED turns on) and the message is successfully received (red LED does *not* turn on).

However, on the second transmission of a message (another call to `CAN_Transmit_Message()`), the transmit once again succeeds, but the receive fails (red LED turns on).

I created this code by following the structure in the CAN_Networking example code, but I cannot figure out why it is failing at the `HAL_CAN_Receive_IT` function on the second message (after the first message is successfully received).

*Note*: After reading the *stm32f4xx_HAL_CAN* library file, I noticed there are two types of receive/transmit:

1. HAL_CAN_Transmit_IT/HAL_CAN_Receive_IT
2. HAL_CAN_Transmit/HAL_CAN_Receive

It says that 1. is nonblocking - I take it this means that another interrupt can be triggered whilst this transmit/receive is still running?

In my case I want to make sure that I receive the response data after sending the transmit to request it, so should I use function 2.? I.e. I would call HAL_CAN_Transmit with a suitable timeout, and then after it completes call HAL_CAN_Receive, again with a suitable timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Do you call HAL_CAN_Receive_IT each time you get a response?

It's one shot. To keep receiving, call it again in your interrupt handler.

From the Reference Manual:
When a message has been received, it is available to the software in the FIFO output mailbox. ***Once the software has handled the message (e.g. read it) the software must release the FIFO output mailbox by means of the RFOM bit in the CAN_RFR register to make the next incoming message available***.

HAL_CAN_Receive_IT contains lines that enable the interrupts and release the FIFO...

```
/* Enable interrupts: */
    /*  - Enable Error warning Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Error passive Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Bus-off Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Last error code Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Error Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Transmit mailbox empty Interrupt */
    __HAL_CAN_ENABLE_IT(hcan, CAN_IT_EWG |
                              CAN_IT_EPV |
                              CAN_IT_BOF |
                              CAN_IT_LEC |
                              CAN_IT_ERR |
                              CAN_IT_TME  );   
    /* Process unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(hcan);

    if (FIFONumber == CAN_FIFO0)
    {
      /* Enable FIFO 0 message pending Interrupt */   
      __HAL_CAN_ENABLE_IT(hcan, CAN_IT_FMP0);
    }
    else
    {
      /* Enable FIFO 1 message pending Interrupt */
      __HAL_CAN_ENABLE_IT(hcan, CAN_IT_FMP1);
    }
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Why is it necessary? What is the theory of operation? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44853983/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).